# Problems with path variable in Spring Boot + React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring, spring-boot, react-router

So, I have a problem here. When I use my React app separately without Spring it works perfectly fine. I am able to go wherever I want in whatever order I want.
Things getting hard when Spring Boot comes into play. If I launch my Spring Boot jar (frontend included) app works perfectly if I move through it via Router Links (I start at localhost:8080 and can move from there to /num/123 for example), but if I just type localhost:8080/num/123 it doesn't work. Browser window is white (html code is there). Browser console shows GET http://localhost:8080/num/built/bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 pointing on  line in my html.

Looks like it happens when refreshing any page except root. My guess is that it is that I made my Controller in a wrong way and it somehow messes up path to my bundle.js for non-root pages.

Backend looks fine, it uses "index" method as intended, it recognises the value of {number} path variable.

I've spent almost a day trying to solve it and I have no idea. Please help :D

Here are important parts of my code.

My controller:

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping(value= {"/", "/num", "/num/{number}"}) 
    public String index(@PathVariable(require - false) String number) { return index; } 
}
```

Main React file:

```
function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/">
                        <MainMenu />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/num/:number">
                        <NumberMenu />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="*">
                        <Redirect to="/" />
                    </Route>
                </Switch>
           </Router>
       </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything I had to do is slightly changing the same line in my html file.
I changed

```
    <script src="built/bundle.js"></script>
```

to

```
    <script src="/built/bundle.js"></script>
```